# How to I make sure my threads aren't overloaded?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am new to coding threads. I have `5,000,000` tasks I need to do with only `9` threads available. My current code seems to be creating more tasks than the available threads. I haven't done the calculation but it roughly means I will have ~4,999,900 tasks in the queue when only 100 tasks have been completed (you get the point). This means the memory is being used inefficiently. I could've had 81 tasks in the queue with 9 threads, and as soon as 1 task is complete, I add a new task to the queue rather than making all 5,000,000 tasks at once.

My question is, how do I make the task queue smaller (say 81 tasks) and then once a task is complete, I add a new task to the queue. Hence, maintaining an 81 task queue. Also, I append the thread `threads.append(executor.submit(do_task, i))` to the `threads` list. That also means the `threads` list is going to be 5,000,000 long at the end of execution, hence, inefficient. I only append the threads so it doesn't jump the code to the printing of `nums`. How can I fix that too? While making sure `print(f'Nums: {nums}')` is only printed once all 5,000,000 tasks have been completed.

```
import threading
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def do_task(i):
    time.sleep(2)
    nums.append(i)
    print(f'Thread: {threading.current_thread()} | i = {i}')

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=9)
threads = []
nums = []
for i in range(0, 5000000):
    time.sleep(0.5) # this sleep function represents me creating the task for the thread to do
    print(f'About to submit {i}')
    threads.append(executor.submit(do_task, i))

print(f'Thread count: {len(threads)}')
for thread in threads:
    thread.result()

print(f'Nums: {nums}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one easy-enough way, using the package's flexible `wait()` function:

```py
import threading
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait, FIRST_COMPLETED

NTODO = 5000000
MOST_AT_ONCE = 12

def do_task(i):
    time.sleep(2)
    nums.append(i)
    print(f'Thread: {threading.current_thread()} | i = {i}')

def consume(threads, max_to_leave=MOST_AT_ONCE):
    while len(threads) > max_to_leave:
        done, _ = wait(threads, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for t in done:
            print(f'closing out i = {threads[t]}')
            t.result()
            del threads[t]

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=9)
threads = {}
nums = []
for i in range(0, NTODO):
    time.sleep(0.5) # this sleep function represents me creating the task for the thread to do
    print(f'About to submit {i}')
    threads[executor.submit(do_task, i)] = i
    consume(threads)
consume(threads, 0)

print(f'Thread count: {len(threads)}')
print(f'Nums: {nums}')
```

Most of that is just adding new bells & whistles to what you already wrote.

Instead of using a list for threads, it uses a dict with thread keys, because deletion of an arbitrary dict key is efficient. And it's a dict instead of a set so that the thread can be mapped back to the integer originally passed to the thread. That's to make things clearer - it's not at all essential.

So after firing off a new thread task, `consume(threads)` is called to *wait* until at most `MOST_AT_ONCE` threads are still working. The result is retrieved for each thread that completes work while it's waiting, and the thread is removed from `threads`.

After the main loop ends, `consume(threads, 0)` is called to wait until no (0) threads are still running.

BTW, to make this easier for you to follow at first, I continued to use your names. In particular, `threads`. But that's misleading, and you should get over it ;-) `.submit()` returns a `Future` object, *not* a thread object. Indeed, that's why this code works at all. Thread objects are reused, but each `Future` object is unique, which makes `Future` objects *suitable* as dict keys (or set elements).

Comment: In this case the most items in the queue will be 12? Is that right? Also for this line `threads[executor.submit(do_task, i)] = i`, why does it `= i`? Why not equal to `None`?

Comment: The most items in the queue after `consume()` returns will be 12. It may go up to 13 before `consume()` is called. It's not delicate. Make it, e.g., 81 if you like. For the other, setting the dict value to `i` was simply so that the `print(f'closing out i = {threads[t]}')` output line could identify which integer completed. As already said, that's not essential. Fine if you use `None` instead - but, if so, it would make more sense to use a set than a dict (and use `threads.remove(t)` instead of `del threads[t]`).